# Why is adding "-feature" to scalacOptions on global.sbt not working?

Tags: scala, sbt

I was trying to include the `"-feature"` value of `scalacOption` straight into my  `.sbt/0.13/global.sbt` rather than using the `build.sbt` file of each individual project.

However, when I do that it does not display the warnings as it would if I added it to `build.sbt` in the project itself.

I tried adding it manually, as a single line:

`scalacOptions += "-feature"`

I couldn't find any answers on [global settings](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Basic-Def.html) or [build definitions](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Basic-Def.html).

Is it necessary that this goes each project's individual `build.sbt`?

I'd appreciate any assistance.

Thank you.